# how to add my android app in facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I want to add my app to facebook. In facebook If I search any app or game like(Candy Crush) its open. I have created one android app and published it to play store. Now I want on facebook like I search any other app. I am able to search my app. How to add my app to facebook?

Edit-

**I am little confused with few answers first thing I have already created app. Now I don't know what to do with android SDK and what's the need of it. Second thing I want to integrate my app to Facebook app center. Don't want to integrate Facebook to my app.**

Comment: Soo... you want the app to be on the Facebook web site so people can play it on their web browser? If so, you will need to re-code the app in Flash then submit it to Facebook IIRC

Comment: Yes how to do this? Any link for reference?

Comment: Google for how to make game in Flash? Or look at amalBit's answer with the link to [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas/](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas/)

Answer (score 2):

## Edit:

- An [extensive guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas/) to create webapp like candycrush within the core facebook experience.
- You can create a web app and then register it with facebook. This way, your app will be visible in the app center, but when the user clicks . it will take the user to your webpage.
  Here is an extensive guide to link your webapp on the [facebook app center.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/appcenter/)

---

Facebook has huge amounts of user information. Facebook lets any app developer access a user's info if they have the user's consent. If you need to leverage the userInfo with facebook, you need to follow these procedure:

1. Register as a developer with [facebook.](https://developers.facebook.com/)
2. Once you are signed in as developer, you will find options to create application.[image]
   [image]

Assuming that you created your first facebook app with the name and namespace. This app is like a passport for accessing all the facebook data.

Facebook provides sdk(software development kits) to make interactions between the facebook server easier.

- [Facebook SDK for iOS.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios)
- [Facebook SDK for Android.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/)
- [Facebook SDK for Web.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript)
- [Facebook SDK for Game Development.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/)

Developers of CandyCrush use *Facebook SDK for Game Development.*Since you are going to develop app for Android, you need to integrate facebook android SDK. The following steps:

- Download the [Android SDK.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/)
- Add your android app details(These details should be exactly same) in the facebook Dashboard.
  [image]
- You can run all the facebook sample apps that come with the sdk to know how you can access the facebook details in your app.

[To make your app listed in Facebook App center.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/appcenter/)

---

*Previous Answer:*
 - Create an app in facebook server.
 - Integrate facebook sdk in your android app.

A detailed info regarding this is found [here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/)

[This](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/) is a more simple tutorial, with step by step instruction.

Comment: I have already checked this link. But I found difficult to understand. I am using ADT bundle so what to do with facebook sdk? Any easy link than this?

Comment: Check my answer now, this is the simplest you can get, to integrate fb in your android app. Hope its helps.

Comment: Yeah, don't get too confused by the similar name, they are both "software develpment kits" and you can use both at once. They are both mostly collections of libraries that give your code new capabilities.

Comment: When I try your answer and if I have some problem. I let you inform and if successful then accept your answer. For know this for your help.

Comment: @amalBit where to add apk file?

Comment: Adding apk? , I am not understanding.

Answer (score 1):

This a complete [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/link-to-your-native-app/) from Facebook to link your app to facebook

Answer (score 0):

Have you made you app public for Facebook? See [this](http://haozhenxiao.wordpress.com/).

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. Nothing I have done on facebook so far. What I have? I have only APK file that I published on playstore. I want to know everything from start.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here you can check facebook application step by step guide..

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Facebook-Application

Comment: No this is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have an Android APK, and I have to assume you want to have your app playable on the web browser. You can't play an Android game on the Facebook website. I assume you will need to entirely recode the game for Adobe Flash then submit it to Facebook.